# Spatial autocorrelation has p value of 0.0000

Tags: arcgis-desktop, moran-index

I have just conducted a spatial autocorrelation test with data in adjacent polygons, and have a p value of 0.000000. I used inverse distance, with 0 as the threshold distance. I am confused as to why the p value is so low.

Is this plausible, or does this indicate that I've made an error?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variance is tiny (0.000026) compared to your Moran Index value (0.053309), so your Z score is huge (11.23) so the p-value is tiny (less than 0.00000049999 if the code is rounding). Your data are about 11 standard deviations away from zero. Hence the small  p-value. You can confidently reject the null hypothesis of no spatial autocorrelation.

p-values can be microscopically small. A little artificial test I ran just now produced a p-value of 0.000000000000003715. Normally you'd cite that as "<0.001" or similar, and giving it to 12 decimal places is over-precise, since various calculation factors will mean those decimal places aren't reliably correct. But "<0.001" is correct and sufficient to make the point.